# background-image no funciona en css

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema ya que al poner una imagen de fondo desde el css no funciona.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pepe.css">
<div class="contenido2">
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2<td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>

</div>
```

css:

```
.contenido2 {
    float: right;
    width: 55%;
    min-width: 700px;
    margin: 1%;
    border: solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    background-image: url(logo.jpeg);
```

Tanto el html, como el css, como la imagen están en la misma carpeta pero no se muestra la imagen.

Comment: Hola @Pepe, he probado lo que has publicado y funciona. Revisa si has puesto bien la ruta y nombre de la imagen correctamente. Es posible sea esa la razón por la que no te funciona.

Comment: Y sobre todo asegúrate que el nombre de la imagen es realmente `logo.jpeg` y no `logo.jpg` sin la `e`

Answer (score 0):

Tanto html, como el css y la IMAGEN deben estar en la misma carpeta, así el pathing sería correcto, ya que llamas en el css a la imagen directamente, eso quiere decir que deben estar en el mismo lugar.

A parte, faltan las comillas en el "logo.jpeg".